# Will new bottom plates in basement allow radon penetration?

Tags: basement-refinishing, radon

I am getting ready to finish my basement.  I can use Tapcons or a Ramset to attach the bottom plates of the walls to the concrete slab with drain tile underneath.  Will these holes from the screws or nails allow radon in?

Comment: I've sealed on the cracks in the slab and the sump pump, and then installed my own radon system a year ago.  My fear is that these holes will nullify it.  maybe if I drill the holes, then put sealant in them, then screw...

Answer (score 5):

If you have radon, it's already likely getting in--concrete is permeable. So adding a small nail hole isn't going to change anything. Also note that tapcons don't actually penetrate all the way through the slab.

If you have radon, you need to get a radon remediation system installed. This *will* put a hole in your slab so the radon has a place to go (and then it's vented out the roof).